# Can't change comment color in sublime text editor 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

I have what I would consider the perfect theme colors for my Sublime Text Editor 3 application; however, the only thing that is very annoying and hard to see is the comment colors. They're the same color as the background but maybe just one shade lighter.

I've seen some other posts on here on editing theme color files within Sublime Text but for some reason it seems like the data isn't taking effect. It's like it's going off of cached data or something.

For example, I'm using the "Monokai" theme. I've edited `/opt/sublime_text/Packages/Color Scheme - Default.sublime-package` and searched for Monokai. I changed the hex color code under `lineHighlight`, and restart Sublime. Nothing changes. In fact, I've changed numerous hex color codes under that section and restarted Sublime Text and absolutely nothing has change.d

What am I doing wrong here? I'm running this on Linux Mint 17.3 Cinnamon

Comment: http://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/#!/editor/theme/Monokai → change comment color → `Save` → `Download`.

Comment: [**Long manual**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/516668/199934), if you understand Russian :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done exactly what you said, changed the value under `lineHighlight` in `Monokai.tmTheme` in `Color Scheme - Default.sublime-package`, restarted Sublime Text and it worked just fine. I'm running Build 3103 on Manjaro Linux.

Sublime Text stores its settings and cache `~/.config/sublime-text-3`, I suggest temporarily renaming this folder, which should take you to a freshly installed state. Then make sure Sublime Text really restarts and that your color scheme changes are really in place.

Comment: It was indeed the cache. Figured it had to be! Thanks so much man!

Comment: OS X - `/Users/[your_user]/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Cache`

Answer (score 9):

I was unable to change comments color by editing `Monokai.tmTheme` even after purging cache or sublime reinstall.

For Sublime 3.1.1 Build 3176 editing `Monokai.sublime-color-scheme` works.

---

**1. Open Package Resource Viewer**

[image: Open Package Resource viewer]

**2. Open Color Scheme**

[image: Open Color Scheme - Default]

**3. Open Monokai color scheme**

[image: Open Monokai color scheme]

**4. Add you desired color in `variables`** (pick [here](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp))

[image: Add you desired color]

**5. Change comment color**

[image: Change comment color]

**6. Enjoy your new comments color!**

[image]

Comment: Found a good purple:
"purple": "hsl(240, 76%, 78%)"

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. I found the following way solved my problem.

According to @Саша Черных, one can go to
[tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/#!/editor/theme/Monokai](http://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/#!/editor/theme/Monokai) to create and download a customized theme. Then, in Sublime Text 3, from [References -> Browse Packages...], you can find where your Packages folder locates. Just put the downloaded file "Monokai.tmTheme" in that folder, restart app, then it's done.